# How should an abstract class be written to override method with additional parameters

Tags: c#

I am wondering how I *should* have written the following code?
I wanted to have a base class, and have one of the derived classes override one of the methods in the base class. But I need a different signature for the method that is to be overridden (To complicate things more, that method is buried in a loop).

**How should I have properly structured the following code to accomplish the equivalent of overriding a method with a different signature?** 
(Getting rid of the abstract declaration is OK to do)

```
abstract class ClassBase
{
    public void LoopThroughStuff(int i)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            //DO A BUNCH OF STUFF
            var k = (something determined in loop) //THIS IS USED IN Class2's DoSomething(i,k)

            DoSomething(i); //THIS NEEDS TO BE OVERRIDDEN IN Class2 WITH ADDITIONAL PARAMETER, WHICH I KNOW CAN'T BE DONE

            //DO A BUNCH OF STUFF
        }
    }

    public virtual void DoSomething1(int x)
    {
        //DO STUFF
    }
}

public class Class1 : ClassBase
{

}

public class Class2 : ClassBase
{
    public override void DoSomething1(int j, int k) //I KNOW THIS CAN NOT BE DONE
    {
        //DO STUFF
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `params object[]` ?

Comment: *overload*, don't override.  OR add a default parameter to the existing method.  Oh, or what @Thomas said.

Comment: If you are including `DoSomething(int)` in the public interface for this class, you are promising that all descendents from this class will support this operation.  If this is not intended, consider making the method `private` instead, which will avoid this problem completely.

Comment: I don't understand how if, let's say, the the "k" value for Class2's DoSomething is set during the loop, how would it get passed into the DoSomething call at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance may be overkill for what you're doing.   Reverse your thinking and try a functional style instead.

Start with an array or list (of any type) then use the Select method with a lamba or Func object that will "map" or perform a transform on each element of the array and return a new array or list.

```
string [] array = {"element1", "element2"};

Func<string, string> DoSomething = (x) => x.ToUpper();

var result = array.Select(DoSomething);
```

or more succinctly:

```
var result = array.Select(x => x.ToUpper());
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of options. Here's one: use generics.

```
abstract class ClassBase<T>
{
    public abstract void DoSomething(T args);
}

public class Class1 : ClassBase<Class1Args>
{
    public void DoSomething(Class1Args args);
}

public class Class1Args
{
    public int x;
}

public class Class2 : ClassBase<Class2Args>
{
    public void DoSomething(Class2Args args);
}

public class Class2Args
{
    public int j;
    public int k;
}
```

Comment: Generics is a good idea here. I'd suggest to keep `DoSomething` `protected` as it seems to be required by `LoopThroughStuff` only.

Comment: If the the "k" value for Class2's DoSomething is set during the loop, how would it get passed into the DoSomething call at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Do the base class like the following code, which uses [Function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) which is a type of [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). a starting reference for basic OOP can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656686.aspx#Methods)

```
abstract class ClassBase
{
   public virtual void LoopThroughStuff(int i)
   {
      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
        //DO A BUNCH OF STUFF

        DoSomething(i);

        //DO A BUNCH OF STUFF
       }
   }

   public virtual void DoSomething1(int x)
   {
      //DO STUFF
   }

   public virtual  void DoSomething1(int j, int k)
   {
     //you can keep this empty, as you will override it in Class2
   }

 }


public class Class2 : ClassBase
{

  public override void LoopThroughStuff(int i)
  {
     for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
        //DO A BUNCH OF STUFF
        // set k here as you like

        DoSomething(i,k);

       //DO A BUNCH OF STUFF
     }
  }
  public override void DoSomething1(int j, int k) 
  {
    //DO STUFF
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Hasson, I'm how would the "DoSomething" call inside "LoopThroughStuff" be changed to the overriden version?

Comment: I understand that in the loop inside the base class you need to call  DoSomething(i); with one integer only, this is the compiler job to do the logic and find the right method to call.

Comment: If Class2 is the one executing, DoSomething(i) I want to replace it with DoSomething(i,k) INSIDE the loop. Also, if the the "k" value for Class2's DoSomething is set during the loop, how would it get passed into the DoSomething call at runtime?

Comment: you can override 'public void LoopThroughStuff(int i) ' in class2 to make it call its own version (with two params). and you can pass k the way you want in the new implemetation. I will update the code to show you that

Comment: Thanks, Hasson. I guess that would still leave me with a lot of duplicate code though. Maybe there's real way to avoid it Thanks for the help!

Comment: Dublicated code should be refactored as new methods and left in the base class, you can call these methods from Class2, so I don't think this will be a problem.